# Computers can't deal with limit of $\Delta x \to 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, computer-science

While I was studying about finite differences I came across an article that says "computers can't deal with limit of $\Delta x \to 0$ " in [finite differences](http://1drv.ms/1sB5P1B).But if computers can't deal with these equations does anybody know how they compute $ \frac {d}{dx}$ of $x^2$ and other such equations.Or whether these equations are pre-written.

Comment: After pew's answer, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation. This would be interesting for you. Otherwise, numerical differentiation is very often used.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:Are you saying that Automatic differentiation uses neither finite differences nor derivatives but rather use a number of pre-defined steps to compute derivative?

Comment: @justin the computers always follow some pre-defined steps. What these steps are depends on how you program it. You may use some very primitive definition and then use some set of axioms and definitions from which you _derive_ all the derivatives including such primitive as of $x^2$. Another way would be to tabulate the most common functions and their derivatives and use several rules like chain rule, derivative of composition etc. and get the derivatives of more complex functions this way.

Comment: @justin. Not at all ! In this kind of system, you enter the code for a function and it returns to you the analytical derivative. Have a look at https://www-sop.inria.fr/tropics/ad/whatisad.html. Their software Tapenade is on-line for free.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:could you explain 'analytical derivative' or whether it simply means derivative.

Comment: @Ruslan:The reason why I asked this question is I really want to know whether they are any advantages of using finite differences in computer-science field while we compare it with differential calculus.I heard that finite differences might be good at solving ODE's compared to latter.Is that right or what's the reason behind this?

Comment: By "analytical derivative", I mean the formula which gives the exact derivative.

Comment: Finite differences are a numerical technique. It only gives exact results when the function you're trying to differentiate is linear. All what finite differences can generally give you is an approximation of the derivative. But there are lots of applications where it's impractical to use exact expressions. Exact formulas may be too large to handle and thus not useful for human when what is actually needed is some sort of approximation, e.g. with relative error of $10^{-6}$. Also, some differential equations are nearly impossible to solve exactly, so one uses numeric algorithms.

Comment: @Ruslan:Do you mean that $\sin$ and other series are represented using 'finite differnces' or could you mention an expression where it's derivative formula is impossible to express using an exact derivative formula.I think sin and other series are very large.

Comment: @justin $\sin x$ isn't a series. It's a function. Its derivative is $\cos x$. There's no elementary function for which a derivative would be impossible to exactly express in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @Ruslan:So I couldn't get what you meant by "Exact formulas may be too large to handle".Are you saying that no formula really exist.Or could you mention a formula or expression which might be too large to handle.

Comment: See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+ArcCsc%5Bx%5D%5Ex%5E2%5E%28x+Sqrt%5BArcSec%5Bx%5D%5D%29). This is not really large, but just an example I could make up.

Comment: @Ruslan:oh thanks.If we use finite difference can we solve this derivative?

Comment: Derivative is not a problem or equation. It can be _found_, not solved. Anyway, you can use finite differences to approximate this derivative to arbitrary precision, of course, but not to find exactly.

Comment: @Ruslan:Do you know why some ODE's can only be solved only using finite differences or whether there is any ODE that can't be solved using differential equations.

Comment: You are not obliged to use finite differences for numerical calculations. You can use finite elements, Fourier series expansion, Frobenius method (which sometimes may give exact results), many other techniques. An example of what you can't solve in terms of elementary functions is [Bessel equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Answer (score 7):

A [table of the derivatives of primitive functions combined with differentiation rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules) yields an algorithm that allows a computer program to *symbolically* compute the derivative of any function that is a compound of primitive functions without having to rely on the limit definition at all (computer algebra).

In fact, unlike symbolic integration, this algorithm is fairly easy to implement.

***Edit:** It can only be re-emphasised that symbolic **integration** is a different matter entirely. In fact, while every function that is comprised of elementary functions has an elementary derivative, the same is not true for the antiderivative. This is a consequence of [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and finds application in the [Risch "algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) (which is not an algorithm in the strict sense).*

Comment: whether computer solve ODE using differential equations or whether it solves using finite differences?

Comment: @justin: That depends on the system being used and is a very complex question. Some systems use a hybrid approach even when numerically solving ODEs, i.e. they first transform the equation symbolically (e.g for better stability properties) and then use Runge-Kutta or similar to generate a numeric solution.

Comment: :Whether the algorithm you mentioned uses finite differences to compute derivative?Because I couldn't understand what you meant by "unlike symbolic integration".

Comment: @justin: Symbolic differentiation algorithms do not use finite differences. I added some more information about symbolic integration before reading your comment, but in practice (industry application etc.), ODEs are ***almost always*** solved numerically only, for example using [Runge-Kutta-like methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) which proceed in "small" (but not infinitesimal) steps. Such methods will produce a numerical trajectory of the integral given a fixed initial value but *not* a symbolic representation ("formula") of the antiderivative.

Comment: :I couldn't understand the term 'symbolic differentiation'.I looked in wikipedia but it says about algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but an illustration of automatic differentiation of a formula (I used Tapenade software online).

The source code I submitted is

```
  SUBROUTINE DUMMY(X,Y)
    Y = X ** 2
  END
```

which was interpreted as

```
  SUBROUTINE DUMMY(x, y)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL x , y
  y = x**2
  END
```

and what I received is

```
  SUBROUTINE DUMMY_D(x, xd, y, yd)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL x , xd , y , yd
  yd = 2*x*xd
  y = x**2
  END
```

which now computes both the function $y$ and its derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ ($xd=x$).

Comment: nice illustration.But could you show with derivative of $x^2$.I think that would be simple to understand much better.

Comment: that's good.But did they compute derivative of $x^2$ using just a predefined step i.e it's derivative would be $2x$ or using any formula?

Comment: They use the same rules as you do !

Comment: okay.The reason why I asked this is whether it might be good if we use finite differences to compute a derivative or is there any place where finite differences are used to compute a derivative?